# how to prove $f'(x) \leq \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \leq f'(y) $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

$f(x) = x - \arctan(\ln(x)) $ on the interval $[0,+\infty[$.
How to use  the Mean value theorem to show that $f'(x) \leq \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \leq f'(y)  $, I know that according to theorem , 
$\exists c \in  ]x,y[, f'(c) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} $
 $ \frac{1}{1+c^2}= \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y -x} $ 
 All help is appreciated

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I guess we are tacitly assuming $0<x<y$. And you just have to prove that $\arctan\log x$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, for instance by noticing that $$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\arctan\log x = -\frac{(1+\log x)^2}{x^2(1+\log^2 x)^2}\leq 0.$$

Comment: That's not what the derivative of your function f is.

Comment: interesting question but your $f'(c)=1/(1+c^2)$ is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**
Here is the derivative of $f$ :

$$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x(1+\ln^2(x))}.$$
Observe that
$$x\mapsto x(1+\ln^2(x))$$ is increasing at $(0,+\infty)$ as a product of two increasing functions.
hence,

$f'$ is increasing thus...

$$f'(x)\le f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \le f'(y)$$

Comment: i need more about it

Comment: @KEVINDLL $x<c<y$ and $f'$ increasing thus...